# How to work with a group of people using Zeppelin?

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I a trying to work with Zeppelin on my Hadoop Cluster:

1. 1 edge node
2. 1 name node
3. 1 secondary node
4. 16 data nodes.

Node specification: 
CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5345  @ 2.33GHz, 8 cores
Memory: 32 GB DDR2

I have some issues with this tool when more than 20 people want to use it at the same time.
This is mainly when I am using pyspark - either 1.6 or 2.0. 
Even if I set *zeppelin.execution.memory* = **512 mb** and *spark.executor memory* = **512 mb** is still the same. I have tried a few interpreter options (for pyspark), like Per User in scoped/isolated and others and still the same. It is a little better with globally option but still after a while I can not do anything there. I was looking on Edge Node and I saw that memory is going up very fast. I want to use Edge Node only as an access point.

Answer (score 0):

If your deploy mode is yarn client, then your driver will always be the access point server (the Edge Node in your case).

Every notebook (`per note` mode) or every user (`per user` mode) instantiates a spark context allocating memory on the driver and on the executors. Reducing `spark.executor.memory` will alleviate the cluster but not the driver. Try reducing `spark.driver.memory` instead.

The Spark interpreter can be instantiated `globally`, `per note` or `per user`, I don't think sharing the same interpreter (`globally`) is a solution in your case, since you can only run one job at a time. Users would end up waiting for every one else's cells to compile before being able to do so themselves.

Comment: Thank you @MaFF for your response. I have tried to reduce spark.driver.memory but unfortunately, I have the same issue... 
Any other thoughts?

Comment: Not yet, will try.